# Django Auth user as well as custom users table?

Tags: mysql, architecture, django

So we've been using djangos database authentication for a while now and have recently decided we want to implement a completely new login system for our website.

We are keeping the django ORM as we rely heavily on it for the database modelling tool.

Anyway, the reason I'm asking this question is because we want to keep the Auth_user table so users can still use the admin panel!

So basically at the moment this is what's happen when a user signs up:

1. Signs up with FB, we grab their details
2. We insert their fb details to our NEW user database table
3. I'm trying to find the best solution for syncing this user table with djangos Auth_user table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you might not still be looking but it might help someone else. The best way to do this, in my opinion, would be a simple `OneToOne` or `ForeignKey` on your new model to `User`. In the admin you can override the `User` admin and add an `inline`:

```
class FbDetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FbDetails
    extra = 1 # Or however many you would like

class UserAdminWithFb(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ... # list display etc.
    inlines = [FbDetailsInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdminWithFb)
```

You can then set up a `signal` to update the relevant info and then view in the admin directly with the user.